# how to use python to do a series of commands in terminal

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, terminal, virtualenv

I put the following in my `python_go.py`

```
import os
os.system("cd some_dir") # This is the directory storing an existing virtual environment
os.system(". activate") #because I want to activate the virtual environment
os.system("cd another_dir") #this the directory I can start my work
```

I hope I can run the `python_go.py`, it can do the work mentioned above.

But when I run it, seems it can only do the first step, the rest of it, e.g. `. activate` seems not working.

Can someone tell me how to do it? Thank you!!

Comment: `. activate` what is it??

Comment: why not just create a shell script? What's the point of using Python? And BTW, it's `./activate`, not `. activate`.

Comment: can you teach how to use Shell Script to do the work?

Comment: It would help if you told us what you're trying to accomplish. While having a python script activate a virtualenv is one option, there are many (arguably better) options like having python call your virtualenv application directly, and a few others.
So, what's in your virtualenv that you're trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you don't have to change to `some_dir` to source `activate` so saving these lines

```
. some_dir/activate
cd another_dir
```

as, let's say `go.sh` and doing

```
. go.sh
```

has the same effect

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying to os.system(". activate") to work if it's in the directory some_dir that won't work because the current directory won't persist across calls to os.system().

You're going to be better off calling a shell script that aggregates all three of the commands you want to do and execute that once from the python script.

Otherwise you want to set up the environment for the parent python process using os.chdir() before calling os.system on the activate call.  Also, the os.system(". activate") call won't do what you want because the "dot space" notation will load information into a shell that's going to go away when the os.system call finishes.

Edited (to your followup comment):

Your shell script should look like this (do_activate.sh):

```
cd some_dir
. activate
cd another_dir
```

and the python code like this:

os.system("db_activate.sh").

Keep in mind that whatever environment variables were saved by ". activate" won't persist after the os.system call.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nothing. `os.system()` starts a new shell for each command i.e., all `os.system()` calls have no positive effect: `cd` and `. activate` may have effect only on the *current* shell (and possibly its children).

If all you want is to activate a virtualenv in the current shell then you should use a shell command:

```
$ . some_dir/activate && cd another_dir
```

Note: the command has effect only on the current (running) shell (and its descendants).

[`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) provides several hooks that allows to execute commands before/after activating a virtualenv e.g., you could put `cd another_dir` into [`$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts.html#postactivate) then it is enough to run:

```
$ workon <virtualenv-name>
```

to activate `virtualenv-name` virtualenv and run all the hooks (`cd another_dir` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to install [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which does what you want:

- `workon envname` will source the file and activate the virtualenv.

You can then do `setvirtualenvproject` in the desired directory and you'll automatically go to the directory where the project is located. You only need to do this command once as it'll then happen automatically from then on.